# Rstudio Rmarkdown knit to multiple pdfs?

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

Can I output multiple pdfs for different page ranges (or using some sort of delimiter) in Rstudio?

Comment: Sounds like a case for [parameterized reports](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick I'm using in case you can't find an easy way (on ubuntu, after installing [pdftk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029450/how-to-install-pdftk-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic)):

Aside from the rmd file, I create an R script which edits the pdf generated by the rmd file and splits it into smaller pdfs.

example:

```
# 1 KNIT THE RMD FILE AND GENERATE A SINGLE PDF WITH ALL THE PAGES
rmarkdown::render('~/my_rmd_file.Rmd')

# 2 CUT THE FIRST 5 PAGES OF THE PDF

# 2.1 make up a name for the smaller pdf: 
name_for_the_top5pages_pdf <- "my_rmd_file_top5.pdf"

# 2.2 compose the command that edits the pdf: 
cmd_extract_first_5_pages <- paste0("pdftk my_rmd_file cat 1-5 output ",name_for_the_top5pages_pdf)

# 2.3 run the command    
system(cmd_extract_first_5_pages)
```

It will keep the original pdf and create another one with the top 5 pages.